# Monitoring a JSON or YAML config file and showing the parent of the changed attributes

Tags: json, yaml, monitoring, elastic-stack, splunk

I have a case in which I need to monitor JSON and YAML config files for changes, but all of the solutions that I found only showed line-by-line changes.

For example, if I have a JSON as such:

```
    {
      "server-1": {
          "name": "A" ,
          "metadata":{
             "tags": ["X","Y","Z"], 
             "date-created": "10 March 2021"
          }
      },
      "server-2": {
          "name": "B" ,
          "metadata":{
             "tags": ["W","X","Y"], 
             "date-created": "11 March 2021"
          }
      },
    }
```

If server-2's tags were to be changed, I want to get: **search-1, metadata, tags** as its result.

Does anyone have any ready-to-use solutions that I can use for monitoring purposes?

I am looking for a ready-to-use solutions since the JSON and YAML fields are quite dynamic and contains a lots of fields. I am considering ELK stack or Splunk for this, but I am not quite sure it will work or not.

Comment: [dyff](https://github.com/homeport/dyff) is the second result in a google search, is that what you're searching for?

Comment: dyff is actually great for yaml, thank you! Do you also have something like this but for json? I actually mainly looks the one for json. dyff doesnt seem to work for json as well as it is for yaml files..

Comment: Can you explain how dyff doesn't work on JSON files? It should as YAML is a superset of JSON and thus you should be able to read in JSON as YAML.

Comment: @flyx I tried to run it on a array of dict, but instead of returning of only the 'parent nodes' as it is for YAML, it returns the whole entry. For example, if I changed the tags on **search-1, metadata, tags**, it returns the whole **search-1** entry instead of only **search-1, metadata, tags**.

Comment: This seems strange as dyff should process JSON input just like YAML input if they are structurally identical. Can you edit the question to show structurally identical YAML and JSON inputs where the YAML input yields the desired result when the JSON input doesn't?